# [C#]Перезапись ячеек datagridview по таймеру

Tags: c#, winforms, случайные-числа, datagridview

Есть таблица в которую я пытаюсь в рандомную ячейку перезаписывать значение(добавлять картинку) по таймеру, но ничего не получается. Без таймера добавление в заданную ячейку работает.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private static Random randomInterval = new Random();
    int NumberOfColumns = 73;
    int NumberOfRows = 36;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridViewImageColumn[] column = new DataGridViewImageColumn[NumberOfColumns];

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            column[i] = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            column[i].Name = "Number" + i;
            column[i].Width = 10;
        }
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(column);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
    }

        public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = randomInterval.Next(500, 510);
            Image image = new Bitmap(Resource1.entity);
            dataGridView1.Rows[randomInterval.Next(0, 30)].Cells["Number" + randomInterval.Next(0, 70)].Value = image;
        }
```

Comment: Никакой конкретики. Ни что вы делаете, ни зачем вы делаете, ни что конкретно не получается, и даже пример ваш ни о чем не говорит. Ознакомьтесь, [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: tym32167, что делаю - game of life с помощью datagridview. Создал таблицу и пытаюсь добавить в ячейки картинку (пока рандомно, потом планирую по алгоритму добавлять), если добавлять в заданную ячейку все получается, а в рандомную по таймеру нет, собственно в этом и вопрос. Зачем делаю - изучаю c#.

Comment: `а в рандомную по таймеру нет` - ну так а что это значит? Ошибка вылетает? Не добавляется и нет ошибки? Что тут происходит то? И где ваш [`минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Если я скопирую ваш код как вы его привели и запущу, я получу вашу ошибку? Или, чтобы вам помочь. мне надо копировать ваш код, додумывать, чего в нем не хватает и  предполагать, что у вас не получается? Вы же понимаете, что этого никто делать не будет.

Comment: tym32167, ошибки нет, при запуске просто выведет  пустую таблицу без заполненных ячеек. Весь код(чтобы запускался) утром добавлю(сейчас нет ПК под рукой)

Comment: а вот этот `timer_Tick` метод вообще вызывается? Как у вас изначально ваш таймер настроен? Точку останова в методе ставили?

Comment: Настроен тикать каждые полсекунды, точки останова нет. Все выполняется в 1 классе Form1 : Form, как я понял отдельно таймер вызывать не надо.

Comment: Значит, поместите точку останова в метод и проверьте, есть вероятность, что вы неверно настроили таймер

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берем обычную форму с гридом и таймером.

Форма

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500; 
        this.Height = 500;      

        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.Width = this.Width;
        dataGridView1.Height = this.Height;

        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        this.Load+=Form1_Load;
```

Тут инициализация таймера

```
        timer= new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1500;
        timer.Tick+=timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Дальше, по сути, копипаста из вопроса

```
    private static Random randomInterval = new Random();
    int NumberOfColumns = 45;
    int NumberOfRows = 15;

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Interval = randomInterval.Next(500, 510);
        Image image = new Bitmap(10, 10);
        dataGridView1.Rows[randomInterval.Next(0, 15)].Cells["Number" + randomInterval.Next(0, 45)].Value = image;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewImageColumn[] column = new DataGridViewImageColumn[NumberOfColumns];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            column[i] = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            column[i].Name = "Number" + i;
            column[i].Width = 10;
        }
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(column);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        }
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: Результат]